# How can I install both lib32ncurses5-dev and libncurses5-dev:i386

Tags: linux

How can I install both lib32ncurses5-dev and libncurses5-dev:i386 on my machine?
When I install 'sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5-dev', it said it will remove libncurses5-dev:i386.

```
$ sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5-dev
[sudo] password for cheungs: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for cheungs: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libterm-readkey-perl libjpeg62 python-support libsvn-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  lib32ncurses5 lib32tinfo-dev lib32tinfo5 libncurses5-dev
Suggested packages:
  ncurses-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libncurses5-dev:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lib32ncurses5 lib32ncurses5-dev lib32tinfo-dev lib32tinfo5 libncurses5-dev
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 1 to remove and 652 not upgraded.
Need to get 673 kB of archives.
```

After this operation, 2,041 kB of additional disk space will be used.

I need 'libncurses5-dev:i386' when i compile android. And I need 'libncurses5-dev:i386' when I 'make menuconfig' for rasphberry pi.

Thank you.

Comment: I think both packages contain files which have same names, so in case you'd manage to force installation of both you'd most likely render one of them broken. Have you considered setting up a complete rpi toolchain into a separate directory tree (chrooted or whatever)?

Answer (score 0):

you can see this issue briefly here.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/256487/initialising-the-build-environment-for-android-on-64-bit-12-04

you need to install these packages to resolve this issue.

lib32ncurses5-dev

lib32readline6-dev

lib32z1-dev

Hope it will help..

Comment: Can you sumerise the answer in the link a bit more?

Comment: Try the following command in your terminal...                                         sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5-dev lib32readline6-dev lib32z1-dev